# AND in a PHP foreach loop?

Tags: php, loops, foreach, operators

Is it possible to have an AND in a foreach loop?

For Example,

```
foreach ($bookmarks_latest as $bookmark AND $tags_latest as $tags)
```

Comment: I don't see what kind of situation would call for this. But you can't do it. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Refer to this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313340/codeigniter-passing-arguments-from-view-to-controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always use a loop counter to access the same index in the second array as you are accessing in the foreach loop (i hope that makes sense).

For example:-

```
$i = 0;
foreach($bookmarks_latest as $bookmark){
   $result['bookmark'] = $bookmark;
   $result['tag'] = $tags_latest[$i];
   $i++;
}
```

That should achieve what you are trying to do, otherwise use the approach sugested by dark_charlie.

In PHP 5 >= 5.3 you can use [MultipleIterator](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.multipleiterator.php).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no. You can always put the bookmarks and tags into one array and iterate over it.

Or you could also do this:

```
reset($bookmarks_latest);
reset($tags_latest);
while ((list(, $bookmark) = each($bookmarks_latest)) && (list(,$tag) = each($tags_latest)) {
    // Your code here that uses $bookmark and $tag
}
```

EDIT:
The requested example for the one-array solution:

```
class BookmarkWithTag  {
  public var $bookmark;
  public var $tag;
}

// Use the class, fill instances to the array $tagsAndBookmarks


foreach ($tagsAndBookmarks as $bookmarkWithTag)  {
  $tag = $bookmarkWithTag->tag;
  $bookmark = $bookmarkWithTag->bookmark;
}
```

Comment: Please can you provide an example of this.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do that.

but you can

```
<?php
foreach($keyval as $key => $val) {
  // something with $key and $val
}
```

the above example works really well if you have a `hash` type array but if you have nested values in the array I recommend you:

or option 2

```
<?php
foreach ($keyval as $kv) {
 list($val1, $val2, $valn) = $kv;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, but there are many ways to do this, e.g:

```
reset($tags_latest);
foreach ($bookmarks_latest as $bookmark){
    $tags = current($tags_latest); next($tags_latest);
    // here you can use $bookmark and $tags
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No. No, it is not.

You'll have to manually write out a loop that uses indexes or internal pointers to traverse both arrays at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for completeness:

```
foreach (array_combine($bookmarks_latest, $tags_latest) as $bookm=>$tag)
```

That would be the native way to get what you want. But it only works if both input arrays have the exact same length, obviously.

(Using a separate iteration key is the more common approach however.)